# Flickr AS3: Loading in a photo

Tags: actionscript-3, flickr

I've been able to figure out how to call the Flickr API with the Adobe Lib and get a response... I can get the description, id, etc. But now I'm trying to figure out how to load in the actual photo and add it to the stage.

```
function loadStartingPhoto():void
{
    service.addEventListener(FlickrResultEvent.PHOTOS_GET_INFO, handlePhotoGetInfo);
    var photo:Photos = new Photos(service);
    photo.getInfo("PHOTOID", "SECRET");
}

function handlePhotoGetInfo(e:FlickrResultEvent):void
{
    if (e.success)
    {
        trace(e.data);
        var photo:Photo = new Photo();
        photo = e.data.photo;
        this.photoContainer.addChild(photo);
    }
}
```

I'm starting to think that in order to pull in the actual photo, I need to get it by way of a URLRequest. But that's not how any of the other tutorials are doing it... or maybe they are...

I'm missing some part... can someone help me out?

Comment: Maybe I shouldn't be trying to "getInfo"? I don't know... the documentation for this is horrible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I spent like 30 minutes with Adobe's official Flickr API and threw it away. From the glimpse I got, I would dare to say its the most unusable library I've ever touched. I strongly recommend you to use the REST API through simple URLRequests using this great documentation:
http://www.flickr.com/services/api/

As for your question, you need to put together the image URL using the info sent in every photo node, as explained here: [Photo Source URLs](http://www.flickr.com/services/api/misc.urls.html)

```
http://farm{farm-id}.static.flickr.com/{server-id}/{id}_{o-secret}_o.(jpg|gif|png)
```

Comment: Ah, so you use the Library to call the Flickr API and grab the appropriate information and then call the photo from a URL anyway? ...I'm not seeing the benefit of using the Library. And I'm glad I'm not the only one who's lost a few thousand hairs over the Flickr API. Absolutely horrible documentation.

Comment: Actually no, I don't use Adobe's library... I just use Flickr's REST API... so if I need to search for landscapes I call this URL via URLLoader http://api.flickr.com/services/rest/?api_key=5515081c69388190f38e30c7c5518cf1&method=flickr.photos.search&tags=landscape and use the returning XML to gather the info and put together the photo's URLs...

Comment: Have you experienced the API giving you back PhotoSets with the photos Array as 0? Every single time I call PhotoSets, the photos array is always 0. I'd love to see the contained photos in this Array but it doesn't work. Any ideas?